# AWS Lambda Function invoked by SQS trigger is not respecting the visibility timeout I'm manually setting within the function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I'm implementing my own webhooks service which will send out events to subscribed webhooks.

Overview of architecture:

- events are pushed onto an SQS queue
- a lambda function is triggered by SQS messages (event source mapping)
- for each event, I make outgoing http requests to subscribed webhooks
- non-2xx responses must be retried with exponential backoff (in such event, I change the message visibility on the received message)
- since lambdas that are invoked by SQS will automatically delete the message upon completion I throw an error at the end of the function to prevent the automatic delete

As far as I can tell, the call to change the message visibility is succeeding. I'm wondering if there's something else baked into lambdas that are invoked by SQS. Upon failure from the lambda, is it internally changing the message visibility again? Or do lambdas that are invoked by SQS not respect message visibility changes (this really doesn't make any sense to me). Curious if anyone has any insight into this problem. I was quite surprised to find out that lambda automatically deletes messages upon success since it makes my particular use-case a little clunky feeling - throwing an error to fail the lambda function to prevent the message from being deleted.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: This is actually not the case. I was failing to properly wait for the call to adjust the timeout to finish. As such the lambda was closing before that request was completing. The timeout I'm setting on the message within the lambda is being respected. I'm then throwing an error to prevent the message from being deleted.

Comment: You should mark this as the answer to your question.

Comment: I'm a bit confused with the answers below and this answer. Is it possible to change the visibility within the lambda for messages that need longer processing time or will this fail because lambda handles the polling independently?

Answer (score 2):

The nature of the SQS integration with Lambda is that the integration controls the polling of the messages. The mechanism used to determine if the message should be deleted is that the response from the lambda is not an error. It's not clearly stated in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html), but I believe when an error occurs the integration is going to set the visibility timeout to zero in order to make it immediately available for another process to pick it up. So in your example you are setting it to some number that allows you to retry, but when you return an error the integration is setting the timeout back to zero. If you need to have more control over that process you probably should not use the integration.

Comment: I was afraid that was the case. It seems they actually do state this in their documentation but it's pretty subtle. - "When Lambda reads a batch, the messages stay in the queue but become hidden for the length of the queue's visibility timeout. If your function successfully processes the batch, Lambda deletes the messages from the queue. If your function is throttled, returns an error, or doesn't respond, the message becomes visible again. All messages in a failed batch return to the queue, so your function code must be able to process the same message multiple times without side effects."

Comment: It states it, but it doesn't make it clear that it resets the timeout to do so.

Comment: There is this note that indicates at least one condition where Lambda is not resetting the visibility timeout between invocations. ([source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html#events-sqs-queueconfig)):

> To allow your function time to process each batch of records, set the source queue's visibility timeout to at least 6 times the timeout that you configure on your function. The extra time allows for Lambda to retry if your function execution is throttled while your function is processing a previous batch.

Answer (score 0):

Since SQS triggers for lambdas process messages in batches, using await in a standard forEach doesn't work (forEach does not await the callbacks if they are async). To bypass that, you can create your own version of an async forEach:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

exports.handler = async function(event, context) {
    var sqs = new AWS.SQS({apiVersion: '2012-11-05'});
    
    await asyncForEach(event.Records, async record => {
        const { receiptHandle } = record;
            const sqsParams = {
              QueueUrl: '<YOUR_QUEUE_URL>', /* required */
              ReceiptHandle: receiptHandle, /* required */
              VisibilityTimeout: '<in seconds>' /* required */
            };
            try {
                let res = await sqs.changeMessageVisibility(sqsParams).promise();
                console.log(res);
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err, err.stack);
                throw new Error('Fail.');
            }
        }
    });
    return {};
};

async function asyncForEach(array, callback) {
  for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
    await callback(array[index], index, array);
  }
}
```